# What is a continuous transfer function?

Tags: functions, math-software

What is continuous transfer and what does a continuous transfer function ([like the CLR from SciLab](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.3/en_US/CLR.html)) do? Why is it useful/where is it used?

Comment: A [closely related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93339/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-transfer-function-in-pid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This to be parsed as "continuous (transfer function)", not "(continuous transfer) function". You can read about transfer functions at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_function). In a nutshell, a transfer function describes the frequency-dependent response of a linear time-invariant system. The adjective "continuous" here refers to the distinction between continuous-time and discrete-time systems (as you can see from the properties "continuous-time state: yes" and "discrete-time state: no" on the page you linked to); it's being misapplied to the transfer function, which will generally be continuous also for discrete-time systems.