# What is the purpose of the transfer function in PID?

Tags: math-software, control-theory

In a [SciLab project wherein they build a PID controller](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CC6yONnLSlY) they include a [CLR/continuous transfer function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93296/what-is-a-continuous-transfer-function) between the output of the PID and the multiplexer, which was used to combine the step and the PID output for the graph. I was curious as to what the transfer function was supposed to do and what purpose it served in the project?

Comment: It's rather bad style to ask two [closely related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93296/what-is-a-continuous-transfer-function)s and not to link them to each other.

Comment: @joriki I linked them together

Comment: Can you state in precise mathematical terms your question?

Comment: @Manos Well, the continuous transfer function in SciLab is in the format of (4)/(s^2 + s), where 4 is the numerator of a fraction, and s^2 + s was the denominator. That's what they created in the video. I know if you don't have the function it gives an error stating "algebraic loop"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project simulates a PID controller for a *specific process*, namely the process whose [transfer function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_function) is $\frac{4}{s^2 + s}$.

- The [PID controller block](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.3/ja_JP/PID.html), which defines the *controller*, has a [description](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.3/ja_JP/PID.html#Description_PID) that should help you understand the overall setup of the simulation, including the role of the CLR block.
- The [CLR block](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.3/ja_JP/CLR.html) (see [description](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.3/ja_JP/CLR.html#Description_CLR)) defines the *process being controlled*, by specifying its transfer function.